# How to add multiple Print to PDF printers with different sizes

Tags: pdf, printing

I need to have three different print-to-PDF printers set up with different paper sizes.  I know how to change the paper size (Preferences>Advanced>Paper Size).  However, I don't know how to add more than one print-to-pdf printer.  Is this possible?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done programmatically by writing a cmd or powershell script for mass rollout across a domain. Thus the programmers automated method is copy a duplicate via printui.exe

However for simple confidence 1st time on one or two devices its far simpler to program it manually. (From experience the chances it works first time via commands is low)

Start Printers and Scanners and although you already have one, ADD via "The printer that I want isn't listed"

[image]

***For this testing Create a new MediaPort the name can be changed later*** via programming

[image]

It can get messy here if you don't know the driver's name, on this device MS Print to PDF is active but not listed as an installable option and nor is Windows update drivers!!! If it was easy it would not be Windows.

[image]

**but a test print should confirm it works**

[image]

***If you want to set it like others to ask for a name then change that in port properties.***

[image]
[image]

Now you understand the method and how it fails often you can custom write the cmd code to attempt the second addition or I would simply repeat for the Landscape form.

Thus in my case I have A4P and A4L for the 2 fixed outputs

Comment: Thank you for this suggested method.  I will be attempting it this week.  I will report my success later.